# Copy picture from Document Library to Mysite Profile Picture

Tags: powershell, my-site

Today we have picture of all the users in a document library. 
https://site.url/.../username_jpg.jpg

I would like to use these pictures of them on mysite. Can I use powershell or something else that can export these images to the right user on mysite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a very similar code to @TempaC s answer. Feel free to comment if someone see room for improvements. I have tested this and it worked for my case.

```
#Defining DocLib and MySite
$mySiteUrl = "https://mySite.url/"
$sourceWebURL = "https://site.url/"
$sourceListName = "ListName"

#Connect to the User Profile Manager
$mysite = Get-SPSite $mySiteUrl
$context = Get-SPServiceContext $mysite
$profileManager = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager($context)

#Get the pictures from the list
$spSourceWeb = Get-SPWeb $sourceWebURL
$spSourceList = $spSourceWeb.Lists[$sourceListName]

#Get All users from ProfileManager
$profiles = $profileManager.GetEnumerator()
foreach ($up in $profiles) {
    $spSourceItems = $spSourceList.Items | where {$_['NameOrTitle'] -eq $up["UserName"].Value + ".jpg"}
    if  ($spSourceItems){
        $picturepath = $sourceWebURL + $sourceListName + "/" + $up["UserName"].Value + ".jpg"
        if ($up["PictureURL"]){
            #If pictureURL already exsist
            #Do Something?
        }
        else{
            #If pictureURL is null
            $up["PictureURL"].Value = $picturePath
            $up.Commit()
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Does the solution provided here work for you?

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sharepointcustomizationprevious/thread/40dd844f-3182-4fa1-b779-ebfba8c1d45e

from the link:

```
#My Site URL
$mySiteUrl = "http://mysite/"

#The part of the picture URL you are trying to find
$pictureLibUrl = "http://mysite/<YourPictureLibraryName>/"

#The internal name for PictureURL
$upPictureURLAttribute = "PictureURL"
#The internal name for Login
$LoginAttribute = "AccountName"


#Get site objects and connect to User Profile Manager service
$site = Get-SPSite $mySiteUrl
$context = Get-SPServiceContext $site
$profileManager = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager($context)
$profiles = $profileManager.GetEnumerator()

# url of web where picture library is located
$webUrl = "http://mysite"
$web = Get-SPWeb $webUrl

foreach ($userProfile in $profiles) {


  $userLogin = $userProfile[$LoginAttribute].Value.Split('\')[1]
  $newPictureURL = $pictureLibUrl + $userLogin + ".jpg"
  $file =  $web.GetFile($newPictureURL)
  if($file.Exists)  {      
      $userProfile[$upPictureURLAttribute].Value = $newPictureURL
 }  else {
      $userProfile[$upPictureURLAttribute].Value = $null
  }  $userProfile.Commit()
  write-host "User: " $userLogin " Picture: " $newPictureURL
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't have the patience to wait, so I started to craft my own script, which looked very similar to this one. And that is quite promising since I am not a powershell expert.